# Name attribute of DataMember in WCF looks like not working

Tags: c#, wcf, .net-4.5

I have WCF service exposed to multiple client. In some of client datamember name casing was not proper. My Class properties have invalid property name as per casing standards like

```
public class TransactionParamter
{
    [DataMember]
    public string orderId;
    [DataMember]
    public string orderDetails;
    [DataMember]
    public double orderSumTotal;
}
```

I have tried to change it to

```
public class TransactionParamter
{
    [DataMember(Name= "orderId")]
    public string OrderId;
    [DataMember(Name= "orderDetails")]
    public string OrderDetails;
    [DataMember(Name= "orderSumTotal")]
    public double OrderSumTotal;
}
```

but when looks like data member **Name**  property not working.
I have tried WCF test client and when taking WCF reference it shows peroperty like OrderId and OrderDetails instead of what i thought of the one i declare in Name Attribute.
Please help me in correcting it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe you forgot to decorate your class with `DataContract`. You need that in order to make custom data member name to work.

```
[DataContract(Name="transactionParamter")]
public class TransactionParamter
    {
        [DataMember(Name= "orderId")]
        public string OrderId;
        [DataMember(Name= "orderDetails")]
        public string OrderDetails;
        [DataMember(Name= "orderSumTotal")]
        public double OrderSumTotal;
}
```